Use of nodes in the case of no links PTV Vissim
Im starting using PTV Vissim and I have a question related with nodes
Im doing a simple case:
enter image description here Pedestrian start in the input, they have a main static route (going to the right area) and in the midle area they start a partial route which diverges in 5 sub routes, the 5 gray areas. It is imposed that the maximum length of queue in each area is of 5 pedestrians. Unitil here I have no problem, the issue is when y try to put nodes in order to analyse the attributes of pedestrians during the simulation.
The problem is that I am not sure about how to put correctly the nodes. Im writting this post to know if somebody know where I can find related information, because the only information I have found was using links, and in this case i am not using links.
